# iOS Tip Calculator

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios

I have a tip calculator that displays the tip in USD in a label. This works fine.

**I want to make that the user can divide the tip amout(on label) to how much persons they are.**
So for example if the tip is 5 USD , and the user is with five people , then he is able to divide the tip amount to 5 , wich gives a tip of 1 USD per person.
Could someone help me please ?

Comment: This is trivial... You can learn how to do this kind of thing from many tutorials online and from any book on iPhone development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then this should help you:

In your header you will have an IBOutlet hooked up to your label (NSTextField)

```
IBOutlet NSTextField *myLabel;
```

Then somewhere in your implementation:

```
float myFloat = [[myLabel stringValue] floatValue];
```

Now that you have the float value of your label you can do your math on it.

Hope this helps.